# How to expose an EJB as a webservice that will later let me keep client compatibility when ejb changes?

Tags: java, web-services

Lots of frameworks let me expose an ejb as a webservice.

But then 2 months after publishing the initial service I need to change the ejb or any part of its interface. I still have clients that need to access the old interface, so I obviously need to have 2 webservices with different signatures.

Anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this, preferably letting the framework do the grunt work of creating wrappers and copying logic (unless there's an even smarter way).

I can choose webservice framework on basis of this, so suggestions are welcome.

Edit: I know my change is going to break compatibility,and I am fully aware that I will need two services with different namespaces at the same time. But how can I do it in a simple manner ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think, you need any additional frameworks to do this. Java EE lets you directly expose the EJB as a web service (since [EJB 2.1](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=153); see [example for J2EE 1.4](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Session3.html#wp79822)), but with EE 5 it's even simpler:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface ILegacyService extends IOtherLegacyService {
    // the interface methods
    ...
}

@Stateless
@Local(ILegacyService.class)
@WebService(endpointInterface = "...ILegacyService", ...)
public class LegacyServiceImpl implements ILegacyService {
    // implementation of ILegacyService
}
```

Depending on your application server, you should be able to provide `ILegacyService` at any location that fits. As jezell said, you should try to put changes that do not change the contract directly into this interface. If you have additional changes, you may just provide another implementation with a different interface. Common logic can be pulled up into a superclass of `LegacyServiceImpl`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an EBJ guy, but I can tell you how this is generally handled in the web service world. If you have a non-breaking change to the contract (for instance, adding a property that is optional), then you can simply update the contract and consumers should be fine.

If you have a breaking change to a contract, then the way to handle it is to create a new service with a new namespace for it's types. For instance, if your first service had a namespace of:

http://myservice.com/2006

Your new one might have:

http://myservice.com/2009

Expose this contract to new consumers.

How you handle the old contract is up to you. You might direct all the requests to an old server and let clients choose when to upgrade to the new servers. If you can use some amount of logic to upgrade the requests to the format that the new service expects, then you can rip out the old service's logic and replace it with calls to the new. Or, you might just deprecate it all together and fail all calls to the old service.

PS: This is much easier to handle if you create message class objects rather than reusing domain entities.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here goes;

it seems like dozer.sourceforge.net is an acceptable starting-point for doing the grunt work of copying data between two parallel structures. I suppose a lot of web frameworks can generate client proxies that can be re-used in a server context to maintain compatibility.